# Clearing canvas for redrawing on it after few translation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to clear canvas to redraw the plots with modified values after a click of button. The problem I am facing is after few translations and scaling when I try to use clearRect to clear the canvas I am not able to clear the canvas completely. It is clearing the canvas in the middle of canvas.

So is there a way to clear it completely?

```
var canvas1=document.getElementById('plot');
var ctx=canvas1.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0,0,10000,2000);

ctx.translate(0,300);

ctx.scale(1,-0.5);

// Few more translations

ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

redraw();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to

```
ctx.restore();
```

before you clear it.